# JavaScript's array filter function used without assigning a function - What happens here?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone explain these snippet (just line with the comment above) to me?

```
function wordRate(word, str) { 
    let words = str.match(/\w+/g) || []; 
    // What does these comparison or whatever it is?
    return words.filter(w => w == word).length / words.length; 
}
```

Array.filter expects a function as first parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

What is done here instead?

Comment: that's a new syntax - 'fat arrow function' https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/arrows-es6/

Comment: The first parameter _is_ a function, specifically an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) from ES6, the latest version of Javascript. This one returns a boolean.

Comment: it returns the value of `no of times the word appears/no of words in the string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To really understand this, you have to break it down.

ECMAScript 2015 (the latest version of Javascript, formerly ECMAScript 6) introduced [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which are essentially syntactic sugar for anonymous functions.

Instead of defining a cumbersome and wieldy expression like

```
function(x) { return x*x;}
```

arrow functions allow you to write instead

```
(x) => x*x
```

where function parameters are specified in parenthesis and the returned result immediately follow the arrow.

In this particular example,

```
words.filter(w => w == word).length / words.length;
```

can be rewritten as

```
words.filter(function(w) {return (w == word);}).length / words.length;
```

This is easy to interpret: we're finding what fraction of the `words` array is made up of just a single target `word`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(w => w == word)
```

is equivalent to

```
(function(w){return w == word})
```

Answer (score 0):

so this is a Ecmascript 6 (javaScript 6) feature. look here
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions